# Does Stack Overflow for Teams Business support ADFS + a second authentication factor?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I am in the analysis phase of implementing Stack Overflow for Teams where I work and my manager wants to know if Stack Overflow for Teams Business works with ADFS + a second authentication factor.

Most internal systems require domain username and password + asks for the code generated by Microsoft Authenticator.

Currently I have created a *Basic* team for evaluation purposes (demos for the management) and I am unable to test this myself.

I am wondering if this two-factor authentication flow works with Stack Overflow for Teams.

Does Stack Overflow for Teams Business support ADFS + a second authentication factor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Basic tier doesn't support SSO but the Business and Enterprise tier do. You can read about the security features [here](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/security).

- SSO - SAML, AD (Business & Enterprise only)
- SCIM provisioning (Business & Enterprise only)
- Support Privacy Shield & GDPR